# parameterized data structures in haskell

Tags: haskell, parameterized

Can you advise on how to represent parameterized data structures in haskell? e.g. in an application which represents contents of a garments shop, I might have instances of racks for men's and women's clothes. These parameters can be hierarchical, e.g. based on age groups. So I can have a rack(men(under14)), or a rack(women(adult)). Also, some constraints may apply to the rack parameters, e.g. no baby clothes. And as with java classes, I would need some member functions which would operate on these instances.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Your question is very vague, and worded in OOP terms that are not really applicable to Haskell. Since your question is tagged template-haskell, how are you intending to use Template Haskell? Some concrete examples would help.

Comment: Removed Template Haskell tag, as it is almost certainly not what Rog is asking for.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this:

```
data Rack = Rack {allClothesOnRack :: [Clothing],
                  withClothing :: Clothing -> Maybe Rack,
                  withoutClothing :: Clothing -> Maybe Rack}

emptyRack :: (Clothing -> Bool) -> Rack
emptyRack isAcceptable = rack isAcceptable []

rack :: (Clothing -> Bool) -> [Clothing] -> Rack
rack isAcceptable = updated
  where updated items = Rack {allClothesOnRack = items,
                              withClothing = adding,
                              withoutClothing = removing}
        adding item | isAcceptable item = Just $ updated (item : items)
                    | otherwise         = Nothing
        removing item -- left as an exercise
```

You create a `Rack` with a function that specifies whether a particular item of clothing may be put on the rack. This function can use any property of `Clothing` (not defined in my example) it likes.

e.g. if `isBabyClothing :: Clothing -> Bool` returns `True` when given an item of baby clothing, then you create an empty baby clothes rack with `emptyRack isBabyClothing`.

Use the `allClothesOnRack` function to get a list of all the clothes on the rack.

e.g. `allClothesOnRack (emptyRack isBabyClothing)` will always yield `[]`.

Use the `withClothing` and `withoutClothing` functions to add/remove an item of clothing to/from the rack. They each return `Nothing` if this is not possible (either the item of clothing may not be put on that rack, or it is not present on the rack and so cannot be removed), or `Just` the updated rack otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

> as with Java classes, I would need some member functions which would operate on these instances

In Haskell, there is no such thing as "member" functions. All functions are simply functions.

> Can you advise on how to represent parameterized data structures in haskell?

Sure. First of all, `Rack` sounds like it's just a list, so you could make a **type synonym**.

```
type Rack a = [a]
```

I'll just introduce you to a few features of Haskell that I think might be useful to you. This isn't the only way to do it, but I think it's a decent way to start. The first feature is called **Algebraic data types** (ADTs):

```
data Gender = Male | Female
            deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The type `Gender` has two possibilities, `Male` and `Female`. This particular example is basically `Bool` in disguise. Another ADT:

```
data Age = Baby | Child | PreTeen | Adult
         deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
```

I'm no expert on clothing sizes, so tweak as necessary. Notice I've derived `(Eq, Show, Ord)`. `Eq` gives us the ability to use `==` on values of that data type, `Show` lets us use `show` on values of that data type (similar to `toString`), and `Ord` lets us use comparison operators. With the definition I have provided, `Baby < PreTeen` will evaluate to `True`.

Now, then. Let's define clothing as another ADT. (`--` begins a single-line comment)

```
data Clothing = Pants Gender Age
              | Shirt Gender Age
              | Skirt Age         -- assumed to be Female
              deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Here I've added *fields* to the options. You can create an article of clothing using one of the *constructors*. For example, `Shirt Male Baby` creates a value of type `Clothing`.

As you continue to learn Haskell, you may want to try using **Generalized Algebraic Data Types** (GADTs) and **Typeclasses**. You will probably need to use these features if you wish to create a `Rack` data type with functions on it that leverage the *type* of the rack to preserve predicates such as "this rack only has adult male clothing". However, I imagine these things are a bit over your head right now; instead try dave's approach with my data types, and run through some good introductory material to Haskell, such as [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: An algebraic datatype seems a poor representation of gender.