# Record syntax default value for accessor

Tags: haskell, record, default-value

As I was [writing up an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915896/208257) just now, I ran across an interesting problem:

```
data Gender = Male | Female
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data Age = Baby | Child | PreTeen | Adult
         deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

data Clothing = Pants Gender Age
              | Shirt Gender Age
              | Skirt Age         -- assumed to be Female
              deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Suppose I wish to write the final data type with record syntax:

```
data Clothing = Pants {gender :: Gender, age :: Age}
              | Shirt {gender :: Gender, age :: Age}
              | Skirt {age :: Age}
              deriving (Show, Eq)
```

The problem is, I want `gender $ Skirt foo` to always evaluate to `Female` (regardless of `foo`, which is an `Age`). I can think of a few ways to accomplish this, but they require that I either

1. use smart constructors, theoretically allowing `Skirt Male foo` but not exposing Constructors
2. define my own `gender` function

With #1, by not exposing the constructor in the module, I effectively prevent users of the module from taking advantage of record syntax. With #2, I have to forego record syntax entirely, or define an additional function `gender'`, which again defeats record syntax.

Is there a way to both take advantage of record syntax, and also provide a "default", unchangeable value for one of my constructors? I am open to non-record-syntax solutions as well (lenses, perhaps?) as long as they are just as elegant (or moreso).

Comment: A normal lens wouldn't work, since you can assign the `gender` field with two of the constructors, but not the other. I think doing this is a bad idea; if `foo` is a record accessor, and `foo x` works, then `x { foo = y }` should too.

Comment: How does adding a function `gender'` (or I might call it `totalGender` or `safeGender` or so) defeat record syntax?

Comment: @DanielWagner You end up using `gender` to modify but `gender'` to read (or vice versa), instead of using `gender` to both read and modify. Part of record syntax is that you can use the same identifier to do both.

Comment: Upon reflection, it seems like the things I want are simply in tension. Records, or lenses for that matter, require the getter to work just as well as the setter, and I am asking for a situation where I can use records/lenses, but with either a dummy setter or an extra getter, which are both sort of bad options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to both take advantage of record syntax, and also provide a "default", unchangeable value for one of my constructors?

In the absence of a convincing counterexample, the answer seems to be "no".

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a tension between types and data... which by the way shows how thin is the line.

The pratical answer is to use a default instance as indicated in the Haskell [Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Default_values_in_records). It does answer your exact question since you must give up direct constructor use.

Thus for your example,

```
data Age = Baby | Child | PreTeen | Adult | NoAge
data Clothing = Pants {gender :: Gender, age :: Age}
              | Shirt {gender :: Gender, age :: Age}
              | Skirt {gender :: Gender, age :: Age}
              deriving (Show, Eq)

skirt = Skirt { gender=Female, age=NoAge }
```

then developpers can create new instances with default values, using the copy-and-update facility of the record syntax

```
newSkirt = skirt { age=Adult }
```

and `gender newSkirt`  evaluates to `Female`

I want to stress that this approach leads you to define default values at the type level, which I think is a Good Thing (of course the `NoAge` constructor is the `Nothing` of a `Maybe Age` type).