# Are there default values for record getters in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, record, algebraic-data-types

There is unsurprisingly a run time exception thrown by the following code :

```
data Necklace = InvalidNecklace |
    Necklace { necklace_id :: Int, meow :: Int, ... }
necklace_id InvalidNecklace
```

Is there some natural way to define a value for `necklace_id` when applied to `InvalidNecklace` to take a value rather than throwing an exception?

GHC fails with a multiple declarations error for `necklace_id' if I try the obvious thing :

```
necklace_id InvalidNecklace = -1
```

Is there perhaps some pragma that'll tell GHC to replace it's inferred declaration by this declaration?

I could declare `InvalidNecklace` to be a record by adding `{ necklace_id :: Int }`, but afaik I cannot guarantee it always returns -1, and generally makes a horrible mess.  I could simply define :

```
get_necklace_id InvalidNecklace = -1
get_necklace_id x = necklace_id x
```

but this partially defeats the purpose of records.

I suppose one could create a special `invalidNecklace` value by writing :

```
invalidNecklace = Necklace { necklace_id = -1,
     meow = error "meow invalidNecklace accessed", ... }
```

Are there any disadvantages to this second approach?  I certainly lose the ability to make `meow` strict or unpacked, but perhaps separate debugging and optimized versions could be maintained.  Is there a pragma to locally disable warnings for partially initialized records?

Comment: See also [Record syntax default value for accessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916099/record-syntax-default-value-for-accessor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**(UPDATED BELOW)**

As you discovered, the getter defined by the `Necklace` declaration cannot be further defined.  There is no pragma to change this.

The common practice in Haskell would be to use this style:

```
get_necklace_id :: Necklace -> Maybe Int
get_necklace_id InvalidNecklace = Nothing
get_necklace_id (Necklace x) = Just x
```

Using a magic return value of "-1" is common style in C-type languages with simpler type systems.  But note that `Maybe Int` is isomorphic to `Necklace`, so it adds little in the simplest case (except access to the large number of common functions for handling `Maybe` that may not exist for `Necklace`).  If you make `Necklace` more complicated then `get_necklace_id` makes sense.

For larger projects it is possible to have template Haskell or an extra tool automatically create the `get_necklace_id` above.

**UPDATE:** Using `fromJust` is not a particularly good idea. To get "reasonable defaults" and "no failure modes" you may compose the `get_necklace_id :: Necklace -> Maybe Int` with `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a` (one of the common Maybe handling functions) like this:

```
from_necklace_id :: Int -> Necklace -> Int
from_necklace_id default = fromMaybe default . get_necklace_id

a_necklace_id :: Necklace -> Int
a_necklace_id = from_necklace_id (-1)
```

The `a_necklace_id` is identical to your function that replaces InvalidNecklace with (-1).  Code that needs a different default can use `from_necklace_id`.

Comment: I'll reevaluate whether `Maybe` is suitable here locally, but initially I deemed it inappropriate because I'd end up writing `fromJust` everywhere, and maybe's common functions looked mostly irrelevant.  I've edited the question with another approach.

Comment: You can work very comfortable with `Maybe`s without constantly unwrapping and rewrapping them, e.g. by using do-Notation, the `lift...` methods, `mfilter`, `sequence` etc., as `Maybe` is a monad and more.

Comment: I'm doing various record modifications to various separate records which would require different `liftM (\x -> x { meow=1 }) v` type expressions everywhere because `{meow=1}` doesn't create a function like one would expect.  And `do { x <- v, return Just v {meow=1} }` doesn't improve matters.  I'm ultimately doing a big non-deterministic computation in a list monad, not a single pass computation inside a maybe monad.  `catMaybe`s everywhere help, but just establishing reasonable defaults helps more.

Comment: @Jeff: You could also look into [lenses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767129/lenses-fclabels-data-accessor-which-library-for-structure-access-and-mutatio/5769285#5769285), which make working with records much less of a pain; in the [data-lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens) library, for instance, you'd be able to have `v ^. meow`, or `fmap (^. meow) v`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `fromMaybe` but never found it compelling for this case.

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you have the type Necklace only represent valid Necklaces, and Maybe Necklace for cases where the Necklace might be invalid? Or, avoiding usage of Maybe, something like (note that I'm still not sure what a good naming convention here would be):

```
data Necklace = InvalidNecklace | NecklaceData NecklaceData
data NecklaceData = NecklaceDataRec { necklace_id :: Int, meow :: Int, ... }
```

Comment: In essence, I'm doing a computation that requires reasonable defaults but has no failure modes, probably better off dealing with them once. <shrug>