# haskell variant of records with different field names

Tags: haskell, record, variant

Given this:

```
data Foo = Bar { name :: String } | Baz { nickname :: String }
```

Both the functions `name` and `nickname` seem to be of type `Foo -> String`:

```
:t name
name :: Foo -> String

:t nickname
nickname :: Foo -> String
```

However, the definitions are incomplete since both of the following expressions will raise pattern match errors:

```
name $ Baz { nickname = "Bob" }
nickname $ Bar { name = "Fred" }
```

Is it possible to complete the definitions of `name` and `nickname`, i.e. something like:

```
name Baz { nickname = n } = ...

nickname Bar { name = n } = ...
```

Trying this in hugs yields errors like "Multiple declarations for variable name".

Comment: You can give them both the same name from the beginning. Is there anything preventing that in your case?

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question at this point, but suppose that `name` and `nickname` were of different types - then you couldn't give them the same field name.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8916099/208257

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The field names are top-level functions with respect to scope and thus cannot be redefined or extended. It's as impossible to make them total functions as it is to make `head` one.

Answer (score 3):

Try the -[XDataKinds](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html#promotion) extension, it allows you to promote data constructors to be kinds.

Note that you'll need GHC 7.4.1, which was released just 12 days ago. This is a good time to be asking this question!

Comment: How can you use this to help with record field names?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Well, it won't help you say `name $ Baz {nickname = "Bob"}`, but it will allow you to use `name` as `:: Bar -> String`, which at least makes the problem explicit. As Daniel Fischer said, asking the `name` of a `Baz` is like asking for the `head` of `[]`, so you can't do much better than making it explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'll have a look at the DataKinds extension.